# HtmlUnit: how to extract elements from<svg> <g> tag page

Tags: java, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I'm trying to automate my routine job. I could see the web shows a lot of elements when inspect a element, but when I click view page source I see only Gibberish words. I want to extract the page element can someone help me. My page sample is below;

Note: there is a svg and g tag in the following page

**View page source details :**

```
<body><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="75px" height="75px" viewbox="0 0 75 75" preserveaspectratio="none" class="startLoaderImg" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;margin:auto"><g><image width="75" height="75" xlink:href="data:image/gif;base64,
R0lGODlhSwBLAKUAAIyOjMTKzKyurOTm5JyenLy+vNza3PT29JSWlMzS1LS2tKSmpOzu7MTGxJSS
........  "></image></g><image style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;margin:auto" class="startLoaderImg" id="startLoaderImg"></svg></body>
```

My HtmlUnit java code couldnt find the target element. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `xpath` to fetch value of appropriate tag.

**eg:**

```
/body/g
```

Also you have to learn about the tool for automation eg `Selenium Web Driver`

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebElement userName =
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/form/input"));
```

- See [Xpath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp), please.
- See [Selenium Documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp),
  please.

Comment: Rudziankou thanks for your answer. I'm using HtmlUnit, When I try to get an element by its Xpath, I'm getting following error
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement